# Does (ReactiveUI 6.2) ReactiveList Support Binding in Winforms DataGridView Datasource?

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datagridview, reactiveui

I am re-factoring an old winforms project into using MVVM via ReactiveUI. The binding part works great so far except the Grid.Datasource = ReactiveList doesn't seem to give any update on changing/adding/deleting.

I just wanted to confirm here, since the DataGridView.Datasource support databinding list only, ReactiveUI.ReactiveList will not work here? or there could be some possible get arounds.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been struggling with this, the approach I've come up with is to wrap a ReactiveList on the ViewModel with a ReactiveDerivedBindingList.

I've created a BindingSource based on the item ViewModel class for design time support, then I replace this at runtime:

```
private void CreateDerivedBindings()
{
    this.Articles = this.ViewModel.Articles.CreateDerivedBindingList(x => x);
    this.ViewModel.Articles.ItemChanged.Subscribe(_ => this.Articles.Reset());
    //this.Articles.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;
    this.articlesDataGridView.DataSource = this.Articles;
}

private IReactiveDerivedBindingList<ArticleViewModel> Articles { get; set; }
```

Subscribing to ItemChanged of the underlying ReactiveList (which has ChangeTrackingEnabled turned on) enables items in the grid to update as they are changed. Setting ChangeTrackingEnabled on the derived binding list didn't do anything. This is a brute force approach, I'd guess causing a full refresh of the grid, maybe there is a more finessed approach.

A simpler approach could be to use a ReactiveBindingList on the ViewModel, but I've not tried this as the class is winforms specific and I'm aiming for a ViewModel which could be reused with WPF.

Answer (score 0):

ReactiveList supports `INotifyCollectionChanged`, I don't know of any other way that lists can signal they have changed. I could be misinformed about Winforms Grid though!

Comment: I tried with ReactiveList but no updates when adding items. Then I changed only the ReactiveList to BindingList with everything else stay the same, the grid update notification works right away.